# Nao consigo desenhar outra coisa alem de triangulos no OpenTK 4.6

Tags: c#, opengl

Ola,estou tentando utilizar o OpenGL a partir do OpenTK estou usando a versao 4.6.7 e por algum motivo nao consigo desenhar outra coisa alem de triangulos,ja tentei de tudo mas parece que nada funciona ah e aqui esta o codigo se alguem puder me ajudar agradeco

```
using System;
using OpenTK;

namespace Aprendendo_OpenGL3n
{
    class game :OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop.GameWindow
    {
        public game() : base(new OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop.GameWindowSettings(), new OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop.NativeWindowSettings())
        {

        }

        private int shaderProgram;
        private int vao;
        private int vbo;
        private readonly float[] vertices =
{
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f,0.5f,0.0f,
            0.5f,-0.5f,0f
        };
        private float p;



        protected override void OnLoad()
        {
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.ClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
            this.shaderProgram = gere_programa.criar_programa("C:/Users/usuário/source/repos/Aprendendo_OpenGL3n/Aprendendo_OpenGL3n/Shaders/vertex.glsl", "C:/Users/usuário/source/repos/Aprendendo_OpenGL3n/Aprendendo_OpenGL3n/Shaders/fragment.glsl");
            int[] saida = gere_programa.carregar_buffers(vertices);
            this.vbo = saida[0];
            this.vao = saida[1];

        }

        protected override void OnUnload()
        {
            base.OnUnload();
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.DeleteVertexArray(vao);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.DeleteBuffer(vbo);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.DeleteProgram(0);
        }



        protected override void OnResize(OpenTK.Windowing.Common.ResizeEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnResize(e);
        }



        protected override void OnRenderFrame(OpenTK.Windowing.Common.FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnRenderFrame(e);

            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Viewport(0, 0, base.ClientSize[0], base.ClientSize[1]);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Clear(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);


            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.UseProgram(this.shaderProgram);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Uniform1(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.GetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"p"), p);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.BindVertexArray(this.vao);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.DrawArrays(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PrimitiveType.Triangles,0,3);


            SwapBuffers();


        }

    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main()
       {
            
            game janela = new game();

            janela.UpdateFrequency = 30;
            janela.RenderFrequency = 30;

            janela.Run();
        }
    }


    public class gere_programa
    {
        public static int criar_programa(string vertex_path,string fragment_path)
        {
            // variaveis necessarias
            int program = OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.CreateProgram();
            int vertex_shader = OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.CreateShader(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.ShaderType.VertexShader);
            int fragment_shader = OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.CreateShader(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.ShaderType.FragmentShader);
            string reader_vertex = new System.IO.StreamReader(vertex_path).ReadToEnd();
            string reader_fragment = new System.IO.StreamReader(fragment_path).ReadToEnd();

            // ligar codigo aos shaders e compilar shaders
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.ShaderSource(vertex_shader, reader_vertex);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.ShaderSource(fragment_shader, reader_fragment);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.CompileShader(vertex_shader);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.CompileShader(fragment_shader);

            // linkar shaders ao programa
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.AttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.AttachShader(program, fragment_shader);

            // linkar programa e deletar shaders
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.LinkProgram(program);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.DeleteShader(vertex_shader);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.DeleteShader(fragment_shader);
            return program;
        }

        public static int[] carregar_buffers(float[] vertex)
        {
            // criar e carregar buffers
            int vbo = OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.GenBuffer();
            int vao = OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.GenVertexArray();
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.BindBuffer(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.BufferData(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, sizeof(float) * vertex.Length, vertex, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.BindVertexArray(vao);

            // finalizar
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false,3 * sizeof(float),0);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.BindVertexArray(0);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.BindBuffer(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
            return new int[] { vbo, vao };
        }
    }


}
```

mais ou menos na linha 67 temos a chamada para a funcao DrawArraws com os parametros
"OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PrimitiveType.Triangles,0,3"
se eu muda-los para
"OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PrimitiveType.Quads,0,4"
ou qualquer outra figura e é claro mudando os vertices,simplesmente nao funciona e se eu der
GL.GetError() ele me retorna "InvalidEnum" da funcao DrawArraws acredito que seja alguma coisa boba que eu esqueci de colocar e mais uma vez se alguem puder me ajudar agradeço

ah e outras informacoes que acho que podem ser uteis

versao do .Net core:5.0//
versao do OpenTK:4.6.7//
edicao do Visual Studio(ide que eu uso):comunity 2019

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 1):

No OpenGL moderno não existe a primitiva quad, ela foi extinda, para desenhar um quadrilátero você deve juntar triângulos.

nesse link ele descreve as primitivas do OpenGL, você vai encontrar sobre quad lá, porém vai perceber os avisos de que é primitiva do legacy OpenGL.

Usando GL_TRIANGLES, GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP e/ou GL_TRIANGLE_FAN você consegue desenhar qualquer superfície.

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive

Comment: muito obrigado mano nao sabia disso :)

Comment: Blz mas e se eu quiser desenhar um retangulo eu vou ter que desenhar dois triangulos retangulos "colados" um no outra neh?Ate ai eu entendi mas como eu vou enviar os vertices dos dois triangulos para a placa de video?eu preciso criar 2 buffers ou so 1 ja conta?Desde ja agradeco pela paciencia e se nao souber responder nao tem problema :)

Comment: 1 buffer só, esse link aqui vai te ajudar a entender: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle. A função BufferData é responsável por como a GPU vai interpretar os dados dentro do buffer.